# Sort JSON list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to sort a list in Flutter, that's an object List, I have a model and that model has a property named as isFeatured, I need that all the elements with isFeatured as true be in the first positions of the List.

I mean I could have something like:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Test',
        isFeatured: false,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Test 3',
        isFeatured: true,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Test 5',
        isFeatured: false,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Test 34',
        isFeatured: true,
    }
]
```

And the elements with isFeatured as true should be in the first position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use sort method with custom comparator for bool

```
myList.sort((a, b) => (a.isFeature ? 1 : 0) - (b.isFeature ? 1 : 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use List.sort

```
 var myList = [
        {
          'id': 1,
          'name': 'Test',
          'isFeatured': false,
        },
        {
          'id': 2,
          'name': 'Test 3',
          'isFeatured': true,
        },
        {
          'id': 3,
          'name': 'Test 5',
          'isFeatured': false,
        },
        {
          'id': 4,
          'name': 'Test 34',
          'isFeatured': true,
        }
      ];

myList.sort((a, b) => (b['isFeatured']?1:0).compareTo(a['isFeatured']?1:0));
```